# How to fix OneNote: This section isn't available yet?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

How to solve the following error message from MS OneNote:

[image]

Statement is not true I am seeing it on the original device.

Comment: You see it on the original device but have you synced the original device to your cloud account?

Comment: Even if not, it doesn't justify this message. I should be able to work with the data on original device even if it is not synced. But yes, notebook is marked as synced.

Comment: Your seeing the notification on the original device? Have you tried to make a trivial edit to the note, so it can be save, I assume your using the OneNote from Windows Store instead of the desktop version? There were some pretty big UI differences between the Desktop and UWP versions of UWP the last time I took an indepth look into the program.